# Delete env variable on mac

Tags: environment-variables, zsh

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RXDf.jpg)I need help, I don't arrive to delete env variable with unset.

[image]

I want to delete conda env variable:
I use unset:

[image]

I look to env variable:

I close the terminal and I open it again, here is what I have in my env variable.
[image]

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Anaconda Python distribution is setting the environment variable on shell startup. You need to find that and remove that. Usually, these may reside in `.bashrc, .cshrc, .zshrc, .profile, /etc/profile` and so on. If you unset them in console then it will be set again next time you start a shell. That is also true for another tab in terminal in mac os as it starts a new zsh shell.

Comment: Thank you very much, do you know the difference between .zshrc and .zprofile ?

Comment: You might want to read https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71253/what-should-shouldnt-go-in-zshenv-zshrc-zlogin-zprofile-zlogout

Comment: @Loki : See the man page, i.e. _zshall_, and search for the section titled _INVOCATION_.